# Chamfer the corners of PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

Almost all the PCBs I've seen for now are right angle. But I think such acute angles are not safe for handing, even when installed on the products, it may do some bad to the wires connecting the boards. But why the chamfered corners are so rarely? For cost reason? Or there are other merits using right angles?

Comment: Because it will expensify the manufacturing? One thing I have done before is to plate the PCB edge, which make it smoother..

Comment: Plate the edge? Never heard of that:). Any other reasons beside making them smoother?

Comment: Sure. The actual reason was EMI reduction. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37984/feasibility-of-pcb-edge-plating

Comment: Because it's really not all that unsafe because when we install PCBs in products we fix it in place so it's not rattling around.

Answer (score 2):

PCBs are not knives. An edge won't cut you. If you have wires that can rub against the edge of the board, that's just bad system design, and you deserve whatever ill effects come from it. Chamfering would be a solution looking for a problem. If it's that big of a deal, V groove rather than route the edges. That gives a more angled edge. The better solution is better system engineering.

Comment: Can't agree some of your ideas. I did got hurt by the angles in products assembly.

Comment: @diverger How? Did somebody throw it at you?

Comment: :), I need do some operations in the case where the board are installed